# Eclipse Setting verbose:class Flag for Launch Configuration

Tags: eclipse, flags, jvm-arguments, verbose

The java.exe command supports a 'verbose' flag which enables things like seeing from which file a class loads.  Does Eclipse supporting setting this flag for a launch configuration?

Here's a [site](https://web.archive.org/web/20120303221350/http://extreme-java.blogspot.com/2011/01/java-verbose-options-for-running.html) that explains the 'verbose' flag about which I'm speaking

Comment: Have you looked at the included screenshots on the page you're linking to? Don't they offer enough explanation?

Comment: That's embarrassing :-)  Yes, the answer is in that site's screenshots.  If you want to put an answer for the question, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does Eclipse supporting setting this flag for a launch configuration?

**Yes!** Eclipse supports

- Goto `Run configurations`
- select `Arguments` tab
- click `VM Arguments` and type `-verbose` flag
- Click `Run`

Boom!!!!

Check out the **screen shots** below.

**1)**

[image]

**2)**

[image]

**3)**

[image]

**4)**

[image]